# In Lebesgue measure, why do we do outer approximations by open sets instead of closed sets?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

So from Caratheodory's condition we can show that a set is measurable if it can be enclosed in an open set whose measure is equal / arbitrarily greater than the original set.

What is the reason that we are only considering outer approximations by open sets, and inner approximations by closed sets?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this reasoning correct? Because the fat Cantor set (Smith-Volterra-Cantor set) is a counterexample in both conditions. The complement of the fat Cantor set can't be outer-approximated by closed sets arbitrarily closely because its closure has non-zero measure, and the fat Cantor set can't be inner-approximated by open sets arbitrarily closely because it has non-zero measure and contains no interval.

Answer (score 0):

Note that points are closed, so $\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$ is always a covering of $X$ by closed sets (regardless of what $X$ is); since we want points to have measure zero, this suggests that every set has measure zero, which is clearly undesirable.

However, it turns out that if we use closed *intervals* (or *balls* in higher dimensions) *of positive radius* instead of open intervals/balls, we do indeed get the same theory, and this is a good exercise.